# Deleting a shortcut of a folder which is in $windir

Tags: nsis

My requirement is to delete a shortcut to a folder. The folder named test is in $windir. The shortcut to that folder is on the desktop. My nsis script should delete that shortcut. What is the script line to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the shortcuts target does not matter, a shortcut is just a file with a hidden .lnk extension.

```
Delete "$desktop\nameofyourshortcut.lnk"
```

Comment: the shortcut is of a folder and not a file.... tried this one but unable to execute. In short I have a folder named test in $WINDIR. The shortcut of that folder is on desktop. I need to remove that shortcut.

Comment: There is a special thing called a folder shortcut/junction, it is a normal folder with hidden desktop.ini and target.lnk files inside (Like network neighborhood) Use cmd.exe and execute attrib /S /D * in your desktop folder to find out the type of shortcut it is. Google 0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D for more info about these folder shortcuts (And keep in mind that a normal .lnk shortcut can also point to a folder and that is the most common type of shortcut)

Comment: Programmatically IShellLink is used in both cases but the clsid is CLSID_FolderShortcut for folder shortcuts ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx )

Comment: Anders, Thanks for the help. Could u precisely define me as im new to nsis... And didnt get what u said.....

Comment: I don't really know how I can help without knowing what kind of shortcut this is. How did you create the shortcut?

Comment: Have a test folder in some directory and made a right click on it and send to desktop(create shortcut). Thats it and the shortcut is created... Now i want to delete that shortcut with nsis script... Generally shortcuts are deleted using the command Delete "$Desktop\myapp.lnk." but this folder shortcut is not being deleted... Have a try of that.